# Method for finding the largest positive difference between two pairs of IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers and fixed-point numbers

Tags: computational-mathematics, floating-point, number-comparison, machine-precision

I have two pairs of IEEE 754 double precision (64-bit) floating-point numbers and unsigned fixed-point numbers, and I'm trying to find which pair has the greatest difference.

The fixed-point numbers have two decimal places, so `123` represents `1.23`. The fixed-point number has a range of $[0,2^{32}]$. It is stored in a 64-bit unsigned format that spans $[0,100\times2^{32}]$ to accommodate the full fixed-point range. Both floating-point numbers are in the range $[0,2^{32}]$.

More formally, for pairs (tuples) of floating-point and unscaled fixed-point numbers $(f_a, x_a)$ and $(f_b,x_b)$, I would like to evaluate whether the following inequality is true:

$$\left(f_a-\frac {x_a} {100}\right) > \left(f_b-\frac {x_b} {100}\right)$$

For example, I might compare:

$$(f_a, x_a) = (0.0100000000000000002081668171172, 1) \\
(f_b, x_b) = (0.0299999999999999988897769753748, 3)$$

$$0.0100000000000000002081668171172 - \frac 1 {100} = 2.081668171172 \times 10^{-19} \\
0.0299999999999999988897769753748 - \frac 3 {100} = -1.1102230246252 \times 10^{-18} \\
2.081668171172 \times 10^{-19} > -1.1102230246252 \times 10^{-18}$$

As such, in this case $(f_a, x_a)$ is considered the larger pair.

Another example:

$$(f_a, x_a) = (6.32000000000000028421709430404, 632) \\
(f_b, x_b) = (14.7200000000000006394884621841, 1472)$$

$$6.32000000000000028421709430404 - \frac {632} {100} = 2.8421709430404 \times 10^{-16} \\
14.7200000000000006394884621841 - \frac {1472} {100} = 6.394884621841 \times 10^{-16} \\
2.8421709430404 \times 10^{-16} < 6.394884621841 \times 10^{-16}$$

In this case $(f_b, x_b)$ is considered the larger pair.

While I've shown cases where the fixed-point value closely matches the floating-point value, for explanatory purposes, this will not always be the case.

There may be other cases where the magnitude of the difference between the two sides of the inequality is also extremely small and not precisely representable as an IEEE 754 double precision number.

Critically, this test must work for floating-point values that are very close to their associated fixed-point values, and must not result in any loss of precision. Since there are fixed-point numbers that cannot be precisely represented as floating-point, and vice versa, I cannot convert one way or the other to perform a simple subtraction and comparison in a common format.

While this comparison check could be implemented as a string conversion, that would be an extremely inefficient approach.

IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers are essentially in the following format:

$$(-1)^{s} \times \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{52} {m_{52-i} \times 2^{-i}}\right)\times2^{e-1023}$$

Where $s$ is the sign bit, $m$ is the set of binary bits in the mantissa (or "fraction"), and $e$ is the exponent.

[image: packed bit format for IEEE 754 doubles; credit Codekaizen, CC BY-SA 4.0]

(from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))

Therefore, each side of the comparison can be expressed as:

$$\left[(-1)^{s} \times \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{52} {m_{52-i} \times 2^{-i}}\right)\times2^{e-1023}\right] - \frac x {100}$$

Since the floating-point numbers are always positive, $s$ is always zero, so this can be simplified to:

$$\left[\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{52} {m_{52-i} \times 2^{-i}}\right)\times2^{e-1023}\right] - \frac x {100}$$

Given this, we might instead choose to represent each floating point number as a pair of integers representing the values of $e$ and $m$.

My question is this: given two sets of integers $(e_a,m_a,x_a)$ and $(e_b,m_b,x_b)$, is there a precise *and* efficiently computable (assuming a modern x86 processor with AVX-512) way to determine which of the two is larger given the inequality at the start of this question?

Comment: You are using Decimal in fixed Point Case. Why not use Binary there too ? Eg : 32 Bit Integer Part + 32 Bit fractional Part. That will make it greatly easy.

Comment: The floating point numbers must be IEEE 754 doubles. The fixed point part can technically be in any format as long as that format is capable of exactly representing all integer multiples of 0.01 from 0 to 2^32 with exact precision.

Comment: You can then use fixed Point format like this : 32 Bit Integer Part + 8 Bit fractional Part  [ using 00 to 99 in BCD or similar ] + 8 Bit unused = 64 Bit. The way you currently stated , I can not see the "Exact" format for the fractional Part. When you say `123` = `12.3` , that will work in Decimal. In Binary, it is not straight forward. It will look like `110001011001` = `11000.1011001` in Binary. You can check that yourself when you give a "Concrete" Bit Pattern Example.

Comment: When I say "fixed point" what I really mean is integers scaled by a factor of 100. It's not actually fixed at a binary offset. Regardless, I'm not sure how the formatting of the fixed portion really helps solve the overall problem given the constraints.

Comment: The Over-All Problem is not well-specified , that is the Issue. There is no "modern x86 processor with AVX-512" which will automatically guess the nonstandard format & calculate. That is why I said **You can check that yourself when you give a "Concrete" Bit Pattern Example.** : Try making a Single Set of Pairs in Binary & calculate it & show the result. Then we can make that "Precise & Efficiently Computable" , when we know the Exact Problem.

Comment: Consider why the format matters : **[ ProblemX ]** Check which Date comes first when given Dates in free format "Monday , January 30 1957" & "November 22 1930" : Convert to some format to get the Answer. **[ ProblemY ]** Check which Date comes first when given Dates in DDMMYYYY format 30011957 & 22111930 : Easier but more Processing. **[ ProblemZ ]** Check which Date comes first when given Dates in YYYYMMDD format 19570130 & 19301122 : Very Easy with almost no Processing !

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I meant by that part. I'm not asking about a way to format the data for optimum processing, I'm asking if there's a mathematical approach for resolving the inequality without precision loss by examining the exponent and mantissa separately. The only major reason I mentioned AVX512 is because it allows for vectorised extraction of the exponent and normalised mantissa. The problem essentially boils down to identifying representation error versus a precisely defined vulgar fraction, albeit not always with the closest possible fraction to the value.

Comment: Better to simplify & clarify the Question. Throughout the Post & Comment , you use common format , IEEE Bit Pattern Image & calculation , Exact Precision format , Precision loss in format , Etc. Now you say the format is not necessary. Even in the latest Comment , you use "identifying representation error" without giving the representation or format.

Comment: IEEE 754 double _is_ the representation, and the final two equations demonstrate the vulgar fraction representation part. I thought that was clear.

Comment: That is the Concern : What is the vulgar fraction representation , what is the Precision there , what is the Precision when converting that to IEEE : When we know that Detail , we can think about estimating the error in the required calculation & then figure out ways to minimize that error & then figure out ways to make it efficient !

Comment: Last thoughts on this : [[1]] Why you have gone to great lengths to highlight the IEEE format , while leaving out the fixed Point format ? We can remove all that unnecessary things , while retaining the last Part. [[2]] In the last Part , you have converted $m_a$ to $m_0,...,m_51$ which is useful , & converted $e$ to $e-1023$ (given by IEEE format) & taken $s=1$ which is to make it more efficient. All good. Now , you have given $x/100$ with no format for $x$. Why not ? If that is given , then the Problem gets well-defined & we can figure out the error & then figure out more efficient ways.

Comment: As it says in the question, $x$ is an integer from $0$ to $100 \times 2^{32}$, which I am currently representing as a standard 64-bit integer. If there is a more optimal way to store $x$ or $\frac x {100}$ for the purpose of solving the problem at hand, then you are free to demonstrate that in an answer. The only hard requirement is that the floating point numbers are in IEEE 754 double format. My primary interest is a mathematical process to resolve the inequality without precision loss; if the data formatting aspect of the question detracts from that, feel free to skip over it.